# angular-translate get all translations at runtime

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

Is there a way to get the list of available translations for the current selected language at runtime?

I miss something like $translate.getTranslations()

Comment: A list of all the translations for your website or only the ones you are processing on a certain route/view?

Comment: All translations (key/value) currenty available through $translate...

Comment: No, I think there's not...less considering that you can be using translation in parts and at a certain moment, probably they aren't all loaded

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any way of doing this in runtime. The best you can do is to generate a list using https://github.com/angular-translate/grunt-angular-translate or something similar and then access that list with Ajax.